# Condicionar datos EXACTOS de una cadena php

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
$cadena = "samu,miguel,pedro,samuel";
$idUsuario = "samu";
```

Y la siguiente condición:

```
if (stripos($cadena, $idUsuario) !== false){
    echo 'Estás en el grupo';
}else{
    echo "No estás en el grupo";
}
```

El probema está en que si la cadena contiene un nombre que también empiece por **samu**, como por ejemplo '**samuel**' el programa lo detectara como verdadero.

Lo que quiero es que si el $idUsuario='**samu**' **NO detecte** otros similares, sino que sea exactamente '**samu**'

Si hay otra forma de hacer más efectivo lo que quiero lograr, de antemano se los agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el formato de tus variables es el correcto (que la cadena independiente este separada por comas y la dependiente no) entonces lo puedes hacer de dos manera diferentes.

```
$cadena = "samu,miguel,pedro,samuel";
$idUsuario = "samu";
```

## Metodo 1: Expresiones regulares

La ventaja de las expresiones regulares es que puedes crearlas de forma estica o dinamica, por ejemplo para las variables que pusiste podria funcionar la siguiente

```
^\s?samu\s?,?$
```

Lo que le estas diciendo es toda cadena que empiece con o sin espacio y contenga `samu` y termine con o sin espacios y termine con o sin una coma, si te das cuenta el signo de interrogación significa que es opcional un caracter.

Ahora si esto lo pones con variables quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
$regex = '/^\s?'.$idUsuario.'\s?,?$/m';
```

Una vez que ya tienes eso debes seguir con la validacion, para ello debes hacerlo con `preg_match()` o `preg_match_all()` el cual te va a retornar una coincidencia con la expresion regular.

Ahora tu validacion quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
preg_match_all($regex, $cadena, $matches);
if($matches){
    /*CADENA ENCONTRADA*/
}
```

Con esto puedes usar expresiones regulares para tus validaciones.

### Metodo 2: split e iteracion

El metodo dos es mas simple pero solo funciona si tus valores estan separados por coma o por algun identificador.

Haciendo uso de la funcion `explode()` puedes dividir una cadena en subcadenas y almacenarlo en un arreglo, quedando mas o menos asi

```
$usuarios = explode(",", $cadena);
foreach($usuarios as $us){
    if($us == $idUsuario){
        /*USUARIO ENCONTRADO*/
    }
}
```

### Rerefencias metodo 1

[regex101](https://regex101.com/codegen?language=php) - Aqui puedes hacer pruebas de tus expresiones regulares

[preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php)

[preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php)

## Referencias metodo 2

[explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)